# Django does not serve static files in Debug True

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Here's my setting.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

here is my url.py

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += [
            url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
                {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':settings.DEBUG})
        ]
```

or

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

but when I want to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/website/css/bootstrap.min.css` I get `'website/css/bootstrap.min.css' could not be found`

The static folders are in the root folder of the project, beside of the manage.py

The project structure is:

```
project
    - main
        - urls.py
        - settings.py
    - app
    - static
        - grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css
        - website/zone.txt
        - website/css/bootstrap.min.css
    - manage.py
    - templates
```

One interesting thing is that I can access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css`
but I can't access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/website/zone.txt`

Comment: DIrectory != file.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I can't access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap.min.css` it will get me not found

Comment: "The **static folders** are in the root folder of the project" Please show folder structure.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've added it

Comment: Please pay more attention to what exactly you are trying to do. Looks like everything is configured right, but you're again trying to access folder `zone` instead of file, you haven't listed boostrap files/folders whereas that's where you've started describing your problems and you have mixed paths at least once - at first you posted bootstrap file url starting with `website` and later fixed it. Maybe you are trying to open truly nonexistant urls.

Comment: @IvanStarostin No that's not the case. The zone is a file. The problem is I can access admin and Grappelli folders and their content in the static folder but I can't access the website folder and its content.

Comment: And you've updated the last url and `zone` became `zone.txt`... Other URLs/folders work just fine - this means config is OK.